# How to use threejs version 0.83.0 with aframe version 1.3.0?

Tags: javascript, aframe

I want to use aframe version 1.3.0 with threejs version 0.83.0 because of one script i got online and it will work with version 0.4.0 and i want to add it in version 1.3.0. Can anyone help me with the problem and please tell me if there is another way to do it.

I have tried to use the script in multiple aframe versions and it works fine from version 0.4.0 to version 0.9.0

Comment: This sounds like the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/339067). What are you really trying to do in your code?

Comment: @FiddlingAway I am trying to update aframe rain component (https://github.com/takahirox/aframe-rain) to work with aframe version 1.3.0. I have already updated the script and removed all errors but it is not working as well. if you want you can check the script at https://github.com/faizmulla06/aframe-rain-update/blob/main/index.js

Comment: Would it be possible to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), preferably as a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)? This would show us what the actual outcome is. You would also need to provide the desired outcome - the thing your code outputs when it's working as you want it to. That way, folks of SO would be able to offer better suggestions.

Comment: @FiddlingAway I have added the github repo of a aframe rain component https://github.com/takahirox/aframe-rain . I need to produce the same output as in this repo but with aframe version 1.3.0